# Find 2 functions

Tags: functions

I need to find two functions or rather two sequences, both of which are borderless but actually converge if you look at $min(a_n, b_n)$. The min has a limes but neither of them does for itself and min as in the lesser one not the graphical.

Comment: $(0,1,0,2,0,3,\ldots)$ and ...

Comment: @Filip Do you see what David Mitra is getting at, or do you still need some explanation? (If you understand, you could post your own answer to your question)

Comment: @Peter No,i don't know what's David trying to tell me if you could explain that would be helpful.Sorry for the late response,it's exam week and i can't find the time to check everyday.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David hints at, we can take an unbounded sequence say $S=(1,2,3,4,\dots)$ and we can create two new sequences from this one by inserting $0$s at all the odd positions for one and at all the even positions for the other. For this example you get te two sequences
$$A=(0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,\dots)$$
$$B=(1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,\dots)$$
and more explicitly
$$a_n=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }n\text{ is odd}\\\frac{n}{2}&\text{ if }n\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$ 
$$b_n=\begin{cases}\frac{n+1}{2}&\text{ if }n\text{ is odd}\\0&\text{ if }n\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

Now both sequences are unbounded, but $\min(a_n,b_n)=0$ for every $n$, so this sequence certainly has a limit and it is $0$.

This is a particular example, and there exist many other pairs of functions with the property that both are unbounded, but sequence of minimums of the pairwise entries has a finite limit.